# Redhat : "gluster volume status" shows NFS Server on localhost as N/A and Offline

Tags: centos, rhel, nfs, glusterfs

I have 2 Nodes GlusterFS setup on 2 Redhat 6.7 Servers. (GlusterFS versions are both 3.7.12) Then the "NFS Server on localhost" status on one Server shows "n/a" and Online "N", while it is showing all fine on the another one.

```
[root@webserver1 ~]# gluster volume status gv0
Status of volume: gv0
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick gluster1:/glusterfs-data/brick        49152     0          Y       27149
Brick gluster2:/glusterfs-data/brick        49152     0          Y       1677 
NFS Server on localhost                     N/A       N/A        N       N/A  
Self-heal Daemon on localhost               N/A       N/A        Y       27176
NFS Server on gluster2                      2049      0          Y       1629 
Self-heal Daemon on gluster2                N/A       N/A        Y       1638 

Task Status of Volume gv0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks
```

What services are required to be started (or) what seems to be missed out here please?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
##enable nfs
gluster volume set volume_name nfs.disable off
## restart volume
gluster volume stop volume_name

gluster volume start volume_name
```

replace `volume_name` with the appropriate name for your voume

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

You need restart the `rpcbind` after the `gluster volume set volume_name nfs.disable off`.

Your volume will be like this:

```
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick vol01:/tmp/teste                      49197     0          Y       4321

Brick vol02:/tmp/teste                      49197     0          Y       4619

NFS Server on localhost                     2049      0          Y       4341

Self-heal Daemon on localhost               N/A       N/A        Y       4349

NFS Server on ftp02-sp.dcdsr.local          N/A       N/A        N       N/A

Self-heal Daemon on ftp02-sp.dcdsr.local    N/A       N/A        Y       4647

Task Status of Volume teste1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks
```